# Shown that $f(z)=\left | z^2-4 \right |^2$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Shown that $f(z)=\left | z^2-4 \right |^2$ is holomorphic. I need to prove that $f(z)$ is holomorphic or not. Well first I need to convert $f(z)$ in terms of $x,y$ but I dont understand how to do it.

Ok I correct it. Thank you very much for your comments. This is my development:

$f(x)=\left | z^2-4 \right |^2=\left | (x+iy)^2-4 \right |^2=\left | (x^2-y^2-4)+2ixy \right |^2$

$f(x)=(x^2-y^2-4+2ixy)(x^2-y^2-4-2ixy)$

$f(x)=x^4-x^2 y^2-4x^2-2ix^3 y-x^2 y^2+y^4+4y^2+2ixy^3-4x^2+4y^2+16+8ixy+2ix^3 y-2ixy^3-8ixy+4x^2 y^2$

$f(x)=x^4+2x^2 y^2-8x^2+y^4+8y^2+16$

$u(x,y)=x^4+2x^2 y^2-8x^2+y^4+8y^2+16 and v(x,y)=0$

Finally I will apply Cauchy-Riemann

$\frac{∂}{∂x} u(x,y)=\frac{∂}{∂y} v(x,y)$

$4x^3+4xy^2-16x=0$

Also

$\frac{∂}{∂x} v(x,y)=-\frac{∂}{∂y} u(x,y)$

$0=-4x^2 y-4y^3-16y$

The fuction isn't holomorphic because $x=y=0$ isn't and open set

Comment: No, the second line of your calculation is incorrect.

Comment: The second line looks fine to me. (You're just using the fact that $|z|^2 = z \overline{z}$ and correctly computing the complex conjugate of $(x+iy)^2 - 4$). However, on line three, you write $\pm 2iy$ instead of $\pm 2ixy$. Correct that and you should be good.

Answer (score 3):

To simplify things, one can note that $f(z)=(z^2-4)(\bar z^2-4)$ and that $z\mapsto z^2-4$ is holomorphic hence $f$ is holomorphic if and only if $z\mapsto \bar z^2-4$ is if and only if $z\mapsto\bar z^2$ is.

As a further simplification, note that $z\mapsto z^2$ is holomorphic hence $z\mapsto\bar z^2$ is holomorphic if and only if $g:z\mapsto z^2-\bar z^2$ is. Now, $g(x+iy)=4ixy$ hence I guess you can show easily that $g$ is **not** holomorphic (in any open set).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you advance.
$$|z^2-4|^2 = |(x+iy)^2-4|^2 = |(x^2-y^2-4)+i2xy|^2 $$

$$ = ((x^2-y^2-4)+i2xy) ((x^2-y^2-4)-i2xy) = \dots.$$

Note that, we used the fact

> $$|w|^2= w \overline w .$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$\boxed{f(z)=x^4+y^4+16+2x^2y^2-8x^2+8y^2}$$
 where $z=x+iy$.

( ⌣́,⌣̀)(^◡^ )

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic.  Let $h(z) = (z^2 -4)^2$.  Notice that $f=h$ on the $\mathbb{R}$ and thus by the identity theorem $f=h$ on $\mathbb{C}$.  But this is a contradiction because the two aren't equal when $z^2=i$.  (Note that there is a $z$ s.t. $z^2 = i$ by the fundamental theorem of algebra.)